# Upgrading to Windows10 to v2004 vs 20H2

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have Windows 10 Enterprise edition on my PC and it was down. Then now I want to install Windows 10 by creating a suitable ISO on Microsoft web site. I have read some articles and look at version lists on Microsoft pages then get very confused about the latest versions.

Here are the questions I have:

**1.** Can a user who has Windows 10 Enterprise license install v2004 or 20H2 of Windows 10 Enterprise and continue to use his/her license with this version as well?

**2.** As a Developer, which one is more suitable for me? v2004 or 20H2? I think there is a semi annually update issue, etc. but I do not understand what the differences exactly are?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 2004 and 20H2 at this point are virtually identical.  If you install 2004 you will eventually automatically either install the enablement package which makes it equivalent to 20H2 or you will literally upgrade to 20H2 which is near instantaneous.

Comment: Good explanations, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

**For number 1:**  You need the Enterprise ISO to upgrade.

[Windows 10 Enterprise ISO](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-enterprise-version-20h2/)

> Along with the recent release of Windows 10 v20H2, Microsoft also
> released downloadable ISO versions of the 20H2 Enterprise editions.
> The Enterprise editions are mostly targeted at IT professionals and
> enterprise consumers.

**For number 2:**

I do not believe the Windows version should affect your development needs (not normally anyway).

Windows 10 20H2 is the next feature upgrade along from V2004. There will be another feature upgrade later this year (later in 2021).

So just keep your Windows system up to date. That is a good strategy.

Here is a Microsoft Update page that shows you the various upgrade paths. You should use the license from the organization where you got the Enterprise edition.

[Windows 10 Upgrade paths](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-edition-upgrades)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122623/discussion-on-answer-by-john-upgrading-to-windows10-to-v2004-vs-20h2).

Comment: Unfortunately Windows did not accept my Product Key and requires email form :(

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fc2a968-abae-4e27-833f-6cce114348cd/cant-activate-windows-10-enterprise-evaluation?forum=win10itprogeneral